# Django MySQL DB populated by external script

Tags: python, mysql, django, orm

I am converting a Flask App to Django.  I have external scripts that run via cron every night that populates the DB.

Django works or has an ORM.  My Flask App did not.

Are there any problems with this approach?  Are there pitfalls I need to be aware of?

I am not changing anything about the DB, just inserting records.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You might want to look at writing a [management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-management-commands/) to do this through the ORM.

Comment: Thanks @solarissmoke  I'm just learning and just started using Django.  Wasn't aware of management commands.  Looking at them, they seem perfectly suited for what I need to do.  Will put that on my list of post migration todos.